# MapInfo very slow to start-up

Tags: mapinfo

MapInfo v10.5 is used across my organsiation by dozens of users as a thick client installation.  A small group of users have started to have an issue whereby the time taken for a new session of MapInfo to open can last up to 30 minutes.

I have logged onto each users’ machine and experienced the same problem as them so this doesn’t seem to be profile related.

When checking the Task Manager during MapInfo startup, the MapInfo process doesn’t seem to use more than 1% of CPU and struggles to use above 26mb memory.  When I do this on my own machine the CPU usage goes up to 13% and the memory usage quickly rises to 175mb and fully loads in less than a minute.

Anyway, just wondering if anyone else has experienced a similar issue with MapInfo.

Thanks,
Robin

Comment: What OS (Windows 7 or 8?) - Have tried MapInfo Professional 11.5.1 and there are no issue with start up. There is a maintenance release for v10.5.2 for http://www.pbinsight.com/support/product-downloads/item/mapinfo-professional-v10.5.2-maintenance-release

Comment: Some time ago I had a problem that MapInfo was refering to non-existing printer in network (it was existing in the past but was removed form network). Some default layouts were somehow refering to this non-existing printer and this caused delays.

Comment: The OS is Windows XP.  I don't believe this is related to the version of MI, as this problem has only started occurring recently without any changes being made to the MI installation.  Plus other users around the organisation are using the same release without issue.  Also, the printer settings shouldn't be an issue as this is affecting the application start-up process prior to any workspaces interaction.

Comment: Printers can also be set thru Options > Preferences > Printers. Check that this is set correctly.

Comment: Is MI Pro just launching without any workspaces and any MapBasic applications?

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue on all of our WinXP SP3 machines. Haven't tried it in W7 yet.
One thing that may slow down things is where in some of your preferences, you have printers that are networked setup as default printer or even default save locations on networked locations.
Other than this i just put this simply down to MI being very clunky.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear all, thank you for your responses.  I have managed to speed things up by removing a load of custom symbols from the workgroup folder.  I had placed a few hundred national police symbology icons into the custom symbol folder, and even though they add to less than 4mb in total, removing these has resulted in the apllication startup being 4x faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue and think I've found the solution - if you open the file in wordpad and remove any lines relating to queries (examples below) then that should speed up the opening of .wor files.

Examples of lines to remove:

```
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . obj within National_Rail_Stations . obj  into Query3 noselect  
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . obj within National_Rail_Stations . obj  into Query4 noselect  
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . obj within National_Rail_Stations . obj  into Query8 noselect  
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . Obj within National_Rail_Stations . Obj  into Query1 
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . Obj within National_Rail_Stations . Obj  into Query2 
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . Obj within National_Rail_Stations . Obj  into Query5
```

These lines come straight after the table lines and before the map line

E.g:

```
!Workspace
!Version  950
!Charset WindowsLatin1
Open Table "\\solar\data_Library\Mapping\OS_Data\Landline\Water" As Water Interactive
Open Table "\\solar\data_Library\Mapping\OS_Data\Landline\Boundary" As Boundary Interactive
Open Table "\\solar\data_Library\Mapping\OS_Data\Landline\Building" As Building Interactive
Open Table "\\solar\data_Library\Mapping\OS_Data\Landline\Centreline" As Centreline Interactive
Open Table "\\solar\data_Library\Mapping\OS_Data\Landline\Fence" As Fence Interactive
Open Table "\\solar\data_Library\Mapping\OS_Data\Landline\General" As General Interactive
Open Table "\\solar\data_Library\Mapping\OS_Data\Landline\Names" As Names Interactive
Open Table "\\solar\data_Library\Mapping\OS_Data\Landline\Rail" As Rail Interactive
Open Table "\\solar\data_Library\Mapping\OS_Data\Landline\Road" As Road Interactive
Open Table "R:\12 Library\GIS library\Projects\Overground\LOCIP\National_Rail_Stations"  As National_Rail_Stations Interactive
Open Table "\\solar\data_Library\Mapping\OS_Data\AddressPoint\SE_England_tiles\TQ2504_3499\Addr_Pt" As Addr_Pt Interactive
Open Table "R:\12 Library\GIS library\Layers\London Overground Stations" As London_Overground_Stations Interactive
**Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . obj within National_Rail_Stations . obj  into Query3 noselect  
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . obj within National_Rail_Stations . obj  into Query4 noselect  
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . obj within National_Rail_Stations . obj  into Query8 noselect  
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . Obj within National_Rail_Stations . Obj  into Query1 
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . Obj within National_Rail_Stations . Obj  into Query2 
Select *  from Addr_Pt , National_Rail_Stations  where Addr_Pt . Obj within National_Rail_Stations . Obj  into Query5** 
Map From London_Overground_Stations,Addr_Pt,National_Rail_Stations,Names,Road,
Rail,General,Fence,Centreline,Building,Boundary,Water 
Position (0.0520833,0.0520833) Units "in"
Width 4.52083 Units "in" Height 4.58333 Units "in" 
Set Window FrontWindow() ScrollBars Off Autoscroll On Enhanced On Smooth Image High
Set Map
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: Delete the "preferences.xml" found in %APPDATA% mapinfo folder.

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.se :) Normally this kind of answer would get a post notice added, "too short, not enough context, might get removed", but in this case it seems to be okay. Just thought I'd let you know for future contributions. :)

Comment: I did delete the preferences.xml file and that did not help. The file is located in: C:\Users\"your username"\AppData\Roaming\MapInfo\MapInfo correct? Mapinfo simply added a new preferences.xml file identical to the one that I deleted.